# Redeployed MVC5 dlls on IIS7.5 HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, http-status-code-500

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error and finding no clue about the problem

However I have just updated applications dll and in browser it is not showing any HTTP500 error details

There is warring in Failed Request Tracing

> ModuleName
>   ManagedPipelineHandler
>
> Notification
>   128
>
> HttpStatus
>   500
>
> HttpReason
>   Internal Server Error
>
> HttpSubStatus
>   0
>
> ErrorCode
>   0
>
> ConfigExceptionInfo
>
> Notification
>   EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
>
> ErrorCode
>   The operation completed successfully. (0x0)

I have tried these webconfig settings but there is no error details in browser

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<compilation targetFramework="4.6" debug="true">
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
<asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: this error come when client can't get response from your server.It may me due to your server permission or A Coding Error in .htaccess please contact your admin for this error

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it by these steps

```
Publish settings ->  Unchecked "Precompile during publishing"
```

IIS was throwing 404.3 on precompiled version